# How to find the initial creator of an instance object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var Foo = (function () {

    //constructor
    var Foo = function (callbackFunction) {
        this.callbackFunction = callbackFunction;
    };

    //method
    Foo.prototype = {
        run: function () {
            if (typeof(this.callbackFunction) === 'function') {
                this.callbackFunction.call(???); //??? should be the object that created this Foo instance.
            }
        }   
    };
    return Foo;
})();
```

this is saved in foo.js

I also have the following code:

```
var Bar = (function () {

    //constructor
    var Bar = function (v1, v2) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    };

    Bar.prototype.callback = function() {
        //'this' should be the instance of Bar
        console.log('value of v1 is ' + this.v1 + ' value of v2 is ' + this.v2);
    }

    Bar.prototype.callFoo = function() {
        this.foo = new Foo(this.callback);
        this.foo.run();
    }

    return Bar;
})();

var bar1 = new Bar('apple', 'orange');
bar1.callFoo();
var bar2 = new Bar('grape', 'banana');
bar2.callFoo();
```

again, this is saved inside bar.js

inside Foo, I have this line: this.callbackFunction.call(???);

So, in order to make this work, I have to pass the object that created the instance of Foo to the call function, but how?

Comment: I think you should remove `prototype`. With `Bar.callback` will [work](http://jsfiddle.net/mGPf2/).

Comment: can't you just pass `this` as an argument in `this.foo.run(this);`?

Comment: @basilikum, I think I can, but right now Bar creates Foo, I don't know if it is a good idea to have foo and bar point to each other. That's my concern.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "point to each other". So far, `Bar` knows about `Foo` but not the other way around. That would still be true if you pass `this` as a generic context. You could also pass the context when you create the `Foo` instance and safe it in the `foo` object. But you have to do something like this. In your current setup, there is no way of getting the `Bar` instance inside the `run` function.

Comment: Btw, `typeof` is a keyword, not a function, you can omit brackets: `typeof this.callbackFunction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the `function.bind()` method.

Mozilla Developer Network:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

It might be difficult to find a way to pass Bar into Foo.callbackFunction, but if Bar passes in `this.callbackFunction.bind(this)`, then Foo can just call `this.callbackFunction()` without passing arguments (or using `call`)

There are also some JavaScript libraries that let you do this in older browsers, since `bind()` is a relatively new feature. For instance, in Dojo it's called `hitch()`.

Comment: I think you mean `this.callback.bind(this)`? Good idea anyway!

Comment: thanks, this is better. I have replaced line: this.foo = new Foo(this.callback); with this.foo = new Foo(this.callback.bind(this)); then inside Foo I can just call this.callbackFunction.call(); or even this.callbackFunction();